# OpenBUGS and coda library

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, bugs

I've fitted a hierarchical model with OpenBUGS using  `R2WinBUGS` package of R. Now, I'd like to use the functions contained in the `coda` library to do some diagnostics. The problem is that I can't apply these functions to the object returned by `bugs()`. I need to transform the object returned by `bugs()` in a suitable object. So I did some research in the internet and I've found out [this](http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/wiki/index.php/R/OpenBugs) tutorial which shows how to do it. I tried to run the code but I discovered that it works only if `n.chains=1`. Can anyone generalize it to work with more than one chain?